# Microsoft Release Management and AZURE website

Tags: .net, azure, deployment, ms-release-management

With Release Management for TFS 2013, is it possible to release/publish to azure website?

I have seen tutorials to release to VMs hosted on azure, but that is about it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Release Management for TFS 2013 does not have any direct actions to release/publish to Azure Website. But however, if you are able to install and configure the Deployment Agent successfully on an azure VM then you must be able to deploy automatically on the azure VM. The following articles should get you going.

http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2013/02/deploy-automatically-on-a-virtual-machine-in-windows-azure/
http://support.inreleasesoftware.com/entries/21926057-requirements-for-multiple-domains